# Keras Image Augmentation - Specifying multiple values for image width / height shift range

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras data augmentation for image classification. I would like to specify more than one value for width_shift_range and height_shift_range. For example, I would like augment the images with multiples values of shift ranges such as 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 in one training session. Is there any way of doing this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify multiple values for `width_shift_range` (resp. `height_shift_range`). What it basically does is that it draws a random number `x` from a uniform distribution in the interval `[-width_shift_range, width_shift_range]` (resp. `[-height_shift_range, height_shift_range]`), and apply a translation of the image with a shift proportional to `x` times the corresponding image width (resp. height) .

Here's the `random_shift` function from [keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py):

```
def random_shift(x, wrg, hrg, row_axis=1, col_axis=2, channel_axis=0,
                 fill_mode='nearest', cval=0.):

    # wrg: Width shift range, as a float fraction of the width.
    # hrg: Height shift range, as a float fraction of the height.

    h, w = x.shape[row_axis], x.shape[col_axis]
    tx = np.random.uniform(-hrg, hrg) * h
    ty = np.random.uniform(-wrg, wrg) * w
    translation_matrix = np.array([[1, 0, tx],
                                   [0, 1, ty],
                                   [0, 0, 1]])

    transform_matrix = translation_matrix  # no need to do offset
    x = apply_transform(x, transform_matrix, channel_axis, fill_mode, cval)
    return x
```

**Conclusion:** take the maximum value since you're going to draw in the interval [-x, x], *id est* if you want shifts varying between 0.2, 0.4 and 0.6 range shifts, just use 0.6.